# Why should I create the context in main for a serial queue and in start for a concurrent queue?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, documentation, nsoperation

There is topic about *Thread Confinement pattern* in  [Core Data programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1) and it says that

> You must create the managed context on the thread on which is will be used. If you use NSOperation, note that its init method is invoked on the same thread as the caller. You must not, therefore, create a managed object context for the queue in the queue’s init method, otherwise it is associated with the caller’s thread. **Instead, you should create the context in main (for a serial queue) or start (for a concurrent queue)**.

I just can't get *why* is that? Where is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says why pretty clear in the documentation that you quoted. The operations `init` method runs on the callers thread while the work that happens in the `main` method *may* run on another thread.

Since you cannot share managed object contexts between threads you need to create it on the same thread as you will be using it. Thus, if you use it in the operation you need to make sure that the context is created on the same thread as the operation runs on.

The reason why serial operations create the context in main is that they run the default `start` implementation while you override `start` when you implement concurrent operations.

You can read more about how concurrent operations work in the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html) (tip: search for "start")

Comment: Oh, I've completely forgot that there is no need to reimplement `start` method in non-concurrent operations. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**David** is right.

The documentation is saying that if, for example, you have a `NSOperation` subclass called `MyOperation` and you override the `init` method like the following

```
- (id)init
{
   if(self = [super init]) {

        // your context here       
   }

   return self;
}
```

Then, if you instantiate that operation in the main thread like

```
MyOperation* op = // alloc-init
```

the context you have created is linked with the main thread and **NOT** with the thread where the operation runs into.

Strange things could happen when you perform changes (deletion, update, etc) on managed objects since you are changing them on background but you access a context that is in the main thread.

Override `main` instead and create the context there:

```
- (void)main
{
    // your context here
}
```

Comment: P.S. I think that in iOS 5 these rules have been enforced and you have a crash if you do it.